# Calculating speed from position (latitude & longitude) and time stored in SQLite database

Tags: android, sqlite, dictionary

I have a SQLite database with the following data format

...
2014-02-17T11:06:22.000-05:00 , Vehicle3, 40.820890, -73.935900
2014-02-17T11:06:23.000-05:00 , Vehicle1, 40.803433, -73.945087
2014-02-17T11:06:17.000-05:00 , Vehicle2, 40.798135, -73.946201
2014-02-17T11:10:10.000-05:00 , Vehicle3, 40.820890, -73.935900
2014-02-17T11:10:07.000-05:00 , Vehicle1, 40.802197, -73.945343
2014-02-17T11:09:59.000-05:00 , Vehicle2, 40.804895, -73.941317
2014-02-17T11:13:27.000-05:00 , Vehicle3, 40.820890, -73.935900
2014-02-17T11:13:17.000-05:00 , Vehicle1, 40.794255, -73.951131
2014-02-17T11:13:09.000-05:00 , Vehicle2, 40.810051, -73.937497
2014-02-17T11:15:37.000-05:00 , Vehicle3, 40.820890, -73.935900
2014-02-17T11:15:26.000-05:00 , Vehicle1, 40.789557, -73.954558
2014-02-17T11:15:49.000-05:00 , Vehicle2, 40.813135, -73.937353
2014-02-17T11:18:49.000-05:00 , Vehicle3, 40.820890, -73.935900
2014-02-17T11:19:08.000-05:00 , Vehicle1, 40.782017, -73.960065
2014-02-17T11:19:00.000-05:00 , Vehicle2, 40.817062, -73.938585
2014-02-17T11:22:37.000-05:00 , Vehicle3, 40.820890, -73.935900
2014-02-17T11:22:20.000-05:00 , Vehicle1, 40.778014, -73.962983
2014-02-17T11:22:44.000-05:00 , Vehicle2, 40.822828, -73.937887
2014-02-17T11:25:50.000-05:00 , Vehicle3, 40.820890, -73.935900
2014-02-17T11:26:03.000-05:00 , Vehicle1, 40.774126, -73.965815
2014-02-17T11:28:33.000-05:00 , Vehicle3, 40.820890, -73.935900
2014-02-17T11:28:09.000-05:00 , Vehicle1, 40.770644, -73.968356
...

The first column is day/time, 
second is vehicle id, 
third and fourth are latitude and longitude.

The number of vehicle is not a constant, and changing throughout the day. 
The day/time is depending on the actual recording time which varies by each vehicle.
The database consists of more than a million records, with a sampling rate at every 3 minutes.

My basic thought is to extract the running sequence of a vehicle (group by vehicle), sort the day/time, calculate the time interval and delta of the position (latitude and longitude) between the time interval as the distance, with distance and the time interval I am able to calculate the speed.

Problem is I don't know how to structure the approach into SQLite select statement, and I appreciate any help given.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: Are the vehicles on roads? Or do they travel in straight lines? If they don't travel in straight lines you don't have a hope of calculating their speeds.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I should mention (just edited and added to the post) that the sampling rate is every 3 minute, and hence we are able to assume straight line movement of the vehicle in the 3 minute interval. Theoretically the vehicle should provide the date/time at the perfect 3 minute interval, but due to many reasons in the physical system, there is some delta in the recorded date/time with the 3 minute sampling interval.

Comment: Can we have at least 3-4 more lines of data for at least one vehicle please?

Comment: @MarkSetchell Yes, certainly, I just updated more data into the question. You can refer to the newly updated question. Thanks for following up!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have had a go at this using awk, which I believe is available on Android - it can be readily converted to Perl, or C code.

It uses the Haversine formula to calculate the distance.

It assumes your sqlite dump is in a file called `locations`.

```
#!/bin/bash
awk -F, '
   {
      # Convert date to epoch seconds for added sanity
      tstr=$1;
      cmd="gnudate --date=" tstr " +%s"
      cmd | getline epoch
      close(cmd)

      # DEBUG print epoch,$2,$3,$4

      # Pick up all fields from current record
      vehicle=$2;lat=$3;lon=$4;

      # If we have a previous record for this vehicle we are in business
      if(lats[vehicle]){
         tdiff=epoch-epochs[vehicle]
         d=haversine(lat,lon,lats[vehicle],lons[vehicle])
         speed=3600*d/tdiff
         if(speed==0)speed="0 (stationary)"
         print $1,vehicle,speed
      }

      # Update last seen lats, lons, epoch for this vehicle for next iteration
      epochs[vehicle]=epoch
      lats[vehicle]=lat
      lons[vehicle]=lon
   }

   function haversine(lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2,  a,c,dlat,dlon) {
      dlat = radians(lat2-lat1)
      dlon = radians(lon2-lon1)
      lat1 = radians(lat1)
      lat2 = radians(lat2)
      a = (sin(dlat/2))^2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * (sin(dlon/2))^2
      c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a),sqrt(1-a))
      # 6372 = Earth radius in km, for distance in km
      return 6372 * c
   }

   function radians(degree) { # degrees to radians
      return degree * (3.1415926 / 180.)

   }' locations
```

**Output:**

```
2014-02-17T11:10:10.000-05:00   Vehicle3 0 (stationary)
2014-02-17T11:10:07.000-05:00   Vehicle1 2.23614
2014-02-17T11:09:59.000-05:00   Vehicle2 13.8954
2014-02-17T11:13:27.000-05:00   Vehicle3 0 (stationary)
2014-02-17T11:13:17.000-05:00   Vehicle1 19.1132
2014-02-17T11:13:09.000-05:00   Vehicle2 12.4564
2014-02-17T11:15:37.000-05:00   Vehicle3 0 (stationary)
2014-02-17T11:15:26.000-05:00   Vehicle1 16.6565
2014-02-17T11:15:49.000-05:00   Vehicle2 7.72184
2014-02-17T11:18:49.000-05:00   Vehicle3 0 (stationary)
2014-02-17T11:19:08.000-05:00   Vehicle1 15.5387
2014-02-17T11:19:00.000-05:00   Vehicle2 8.46043
2014-02-17T11:22:37.000-05:00   Vehicle3 0 (stationary)
2014-02-17T11:22:20.000-05:00   Vehicle1 9.53438
2014-02-17T11:22:44.000-05:00   Vehicle2 10.349
2014-02-17T11:25:50.000-05:00   Vehicle3 0 (stationary)
2014-02-17T11:26:03.000-05:00   Vehicle1 7.97182
2014-02-17T11:28:33.000-05:00   Vehicle3 0 (stationary)
2014-02-17T11:28:09.000-05:00   Vehicle1 12.6412
```

**Notes:**

1. Units are km/h, change the 6372 km Earth radius in the code to 3959 miles for units of mph.
2. Your `date` command may be `date` rather than `gnudate` on line 6.
3. If you want to handle the vehicles going offline for a while, move the line that calculates `tdiff` up above the `if` statement and test `if tdiff<60` so you only calculate speeds if the time since the last position is less than a minute (say).

Comment: thanks for the proposal. Can I confirm that there is no easy way to build all the logic into a single select statement? And the better way is to use other language (e.g. AWK in your proposal) to handle the processing logic?

Comment: Hi Lawrence. Sorry, I do not know enough about SQLite to answer definitively, so I would tend to go with @CL.'s answer and experience. By the way, I am intrigued as to what vehicles you are monitoring (and why) on a bird sanctuary island in New York and would love to know (or read a weblink if you have one) if you feel able to answer on a public platform. Also, please consider accepting my answer if it is useful to you - so I get a lovely big green tick :-) Thank you.

Comment: I marked @MarkSetchell reply as the answer with the understanding that it is easier to implement through other programming language rather than through single SQL Select statement to achieve the question objective. Thanks Mark Setchell.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite does not have the mathematical functions needed to convert lat/lon coordinates into metric coordinates (and Android does not allow you to add them).

Comment: Understood that SQLite has the ability to create new custom functions but Android doesn't allow that. However, the answer is still very useful to me if it can be done in SQLite alone (not in Android).