# Create a png file from lat,long,value

Tags: dictionary, awk

I have a program in awk that has an array of Lat, long, values. assume the lat/long are the center of a bin of a grid. For each bin there is a value and I would like to create a png file that color codes each bin depending on the value. For each line of lat/long/value (lets say for a 600X600 pixels or 360,000 bins) I would like the png file to be generated. Each bin now represents about a 30 meter by 30 meter bin size. See picture for example. Assume I woul dlike to have 5 colors for the entire range of values lets say 0-10 is blue, 11-20, red, etc.

the data I have is as follows:
38.0098946, 78.5092495 ,30
38.0101420, 78.5091242 ,20
38.0103893, 78.5089989 ,10
38.0106366, 78.5088737 ,50

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/diTaD.png)

Comment: the png file will reflect lets say 10 colors where the values are divided into 10 ranges, 1 color per range

Comment: This is quite hard to understand but I am pretty sure it can be done easily enough if you take the time to explain it properly. Please show your first few latitudes and longitudes and how the corresponding plot would look. At the moment, of example, your lats and longs might look like 54deg 33min N and 32 deg 18 min W, or maybe 18 and 32 as coordinates on a 100x100 grid.

Comment: What have the colours got to do with anything? You don't mention colours in your question. Also, please don't explain things in comments - it is really hard to read - instead, click `edit` under your original question and clarify your question.

Comment: Still don't get it. Your values are 10, 20, 30, 50 but all the points are red? How am I supposed to know the dimensions of the output image? Come on, please try harder or your question will get closed as unintelligible.

Comment: OK - I updated the question. I think this is as clear as I can make it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative to my other answer, you could write a `PGM` (Portable Gray Map) file, which is described on the same Wikipedia page I linked to in the other answer. So, in the header you would write `P2` in place of `P3` and for each pixel you would write the single value (in range 0-50) that you already have, rather than the three components of a specific colour.

The advantage of his method is that you can then colour the images with a lookup table afterwards and dink with the colours without needing to change your program or the scaling.

So, let's say your program (miraculously) produced this greyscale ramp where the values vary from 0-255 (`output.pgm`):

[image]

And now you want to colour it according to:

- 0-9 => red
- 10-19 => yellow
- 20-29 => green
- 30-39 => dark grey
- 40-49 => light grey
- 50+   => magenta

You can make a Colour Lookup Table like this:

```
convert -size 10x1 xc:red xc:yellow xc:lime xc:gray40 xc:gray80 +append -background magenta -extent 256x1\! LUT.png
```

[image]

And now you can apply that lookup table to your results with:

```
convert output.pgm LUT.PNG -clut result.png
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks this helps. All I need is to map my bins (lat/long)  to the pixels but I think I can do that. I will probably go with the second option since my scale will not change for many other png files I will generate. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I still don't understand your question, as your data doesn't seem to match your diagram, but I can show you how to make a 600x500 PNG with the colours of your choice from `awk`.

The simplest way, I think is to use `NetPBM` ASCII Portable Pixmap format which is described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm_format). I am using `P3` so it is ASCII and easy to deal with but not space-efficient.

Here is an example:

```
awk '
BEGIN{
   # Output NetPBM P3 ASCII Portable Pixmap header
   printf "P3\n"
   # Output width and height
   width=600; height=500
   printf "%d %d\n",width,height
   # Output maximum range (i.e. 8-bit)
   printf "255\n"

   # Set up colors
   color[1]="255 0 0"     # red
   color[2]="0 255 0"     # green
   color[3]="0 0 255"     # blue
   color[4]="0 255 255"   # cyan
   color[5]="255 0 255"   # magenta
   color[6]="255 255 0"   # yellow
}

END{
   for(y=0;y<height;y++){
      for(x=0;x<width;x++){
         # Select new random color every 30 pixels so it comes out "blocky"
         if((x%30)==0){
            c=color[int(rand()*6)+1];
         }
         printf "%s\n",c
      }
   }
}' /dev/null | convert - result.png
```

In the `BEGIN` block, I output the PPM header and set up my colours. In the `END` block, I run through a loop generating colours for each pixel of the image. I use `/dev/null` as a file so that `awk` doesn't hang and it does get to the `END` block.

So, the (intermediate) `PPM` file will look like this in your case - showing the header and the first 3 green pixels of the first row:

```
P3
600 500
255
0 255 0
0 255 0
0 255 0
...
...
```

Afterwards, I tell **ImageMagick** to convert the incoming `PPM` file to a `PNG` file.

[image]

If you need to calculate the distance between points on the Earth's surface (I can't tell from your question), you will need the Haversine formula, which I wrote up as an `awk` function for another answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22289067/2836621).

**ImageMagick** is installed on most Linux distros and is available for OSX, and Windows - [see here](http://www.imagemagick.org).

Comment: You could place the code in the `END` block within the `BEGIN` block. Then you wouldn't need to supply any input whatsoever.