# Linux create Image pixel by pixel in command line

Tags: linux, image, command, line, pixel

Is there a way in Linux to create an image and construct it pixel by pixel directly in command line?

I tried imagemagick, but its only possible to create a blank image without set pixels seperate.

Any Idea?

Comment: Yes, but your question is very unclear. Please give an example. You have a pixel - where from? Where do you want to put it? How many do you have? Why don't you want to add them all at the same time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use shell scripting to build a ppm image.

```
echo "P2"
echo "# Column (width) Row (height)"
echo "$1 $1\n1"

t=`expr $1 / 8`
for i in `seq 1 4`; do
    for i in `seq 1 $t`; do
        for i in `seq 1 4`; do
            for i in `seq 1 $t`; do echo -n "1 "; done
            for i in `seq 1 $t`; do echo -n "0 "; done
        done
        echo
    done
    for i in `seq 1 $t`; do
        for i in `seq 1 4`; do
            for i in `seq 1 $t`; do echo -n "0 "; done
            for i in `seq 1 $t`; do echo -n "1 "; done
        done
        echo
    done
done
```

To run the above code do:

```
$ sh filename.sh 120 > im1.ppm ; eog im1.ppm
```

The result is:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWPcb.jpg)

Answer (score 8):

Ok, so we start with a red pixel:

```
convert xc:red image.png
```

I'll enlarge it - it is rather small.

[image]

Now we get a blue one and want to add it:

```
convert image.png xc:blue +append image.png
```

[image]

Then someone gives us an RGB pixel:

```
convert image.png xc:"rgb(255,255,0)" +append image.png
```

[image]

Now some trouble-maker comes along with an HSL pixel:

```
convert image.png xc:"hsl(120,100,100)" +append image.png
```

[image]

Be careful not to use JPEG though as it is lossy.

Comment: This is clever and could totally be useful for scripts that do ad hoc visualization.  How does one get to the next row in this scheme?  This is the queue model, but is there a way to use convert to "Peek and Poke" colors by x, y address in an existing image as well?   It is probably limited to 5 or 10 pixels a second, though.

Comment: That's trickier and depends on things that OP has not specified. When an extra row is added there will have to be blank/transparent pixels to fill the line since images are rectangular, so you will need to set `-background none` and use `-append` in place of `+append`....

Comment: If you want to poke a blue pixel in at x,y, use `convert image.png -fill blue -draw "point x,y" image.png`

Comment: This could be awesome.  Think of this: Disk IO on a one second interval, scaled by color.  IO per file, where one line is added a second with a color scale for how much IO a file saw in a second or minute.  A network visualization where each column is a unique address (key stored separately)  with the color representing how much traffic went across the connection..  It's visually obvious when there are hot spots, and over time, patterns emerge.

Comment: You can do such things with `awk` or Perl too... http://stackoverflow.com/a/39719293/2836621

Comment: Ah, that would be preferable if you had a bunch of data to convert to visualization at once.